# Circular Progress bar on ImageView using SDWebImage block

Tags: ios, asynchronous, progress-bar, nsthread, sdwebimage

I am trying to implement a instagram like circular progress bar for image loading using SDWebImage.
1.I am using this piece of code but it is not working properly. The progress bar is not getting hidden after image is applied to the imageview.

2. Cell reuse issue is causing some problems also.
3. Also a warning is being issued that I am trying to update the progress bar in a background thread.

How can I get rid of these problems

```
- (void)setImageInImageView:(UIImageView *)imgv withURLString:(NSString *)str_url {

  //GuestDefaultProfilePic
    [imgv sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str_url] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ImageGalleryBackground"] options: SDWebImageHighPriority progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize){

        NSLog(@"the progress is %f", ((receivedSize*1.0f) * 100) /  expectedSize);
        progressView = [imgv viewWithTag:4321];

        if(progressView==nil)
        {
            progressView = [[THCircularProgressView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(imgv.center.x - 20 , imgv.center.y-20 , 60 , 60)];
            progressView.lineWidth = 5.0f;
            progressView.progressColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            progressView.progressBackgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

            progressView.centerLabelVisible = YES;
            progressView.tag = 4321;
            [imgv addSubview:progressView];
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [progressView setPercentage:(receivedSize*1.0f) /  expectedSize];
        });
        if(receivedSize >= expectedSize)
        {
            progressView.hidden = YES;
        }
    }
    completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL){

       [progressView setHidden:YES];
        [progressView removeFromSuperview];
        [progressView setPercentage:0];
        [imgv setImage:image];

    }];


}
```

Comment: hi, @shikhar Have you got the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this,

1. Install `pod "MBCircularProgressBar"`
2. Take UIView on you custom cell as like you want progress view and set class MBCircularProgressBarView.

   ```
   @IBOutlet weak var progressView: MBCircularProgressBarView!


       cell.imgAlbum.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imageUrl), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholderImage"), options: .highPriority, progress: { (receivedSize :Int, ExpectedSize :Int, url:URL?) in

       DispatchQueue.main.async {
           cell.ActivityView.isHidden = false;
           cell.ActivityView.value = CGFloat(receivedSize)
           cell.ActivityView.maxValue = CGFloat(ExpectedSize)
       }
   }) { (image : UIImage?, error : Error?, cacheType : SDImageCacheType?, url:URL?) in

       DispatchQueue.main.async {
           UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.0, animations: {() -> Void in
               cell.ActivityView.isHidden = true;
           })}

       cell.imgBlur.removeBlurEffect()
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a new progressView everytime the progress block is called. Instead, do this:

```
THCircularProgressView *progressView = [imgv viewWithTag:4321];

if(progressView==nil)
{
  progressView = [[THCircularProgressView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(imgv.center.x - 20 , imgv.center.y-20 , 60 , 60)];
  progressView.lineWidth = 5.0f;
  progressView.progressColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  progressView.progressBackgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

  progressView.centerLabelVisible = YES;
  progressView.tag = 4321;
  [imgv addSubview:progressView];
}

[progressView setPercentage:(receivedSize*1.0f) /  expectedSize];
```

Alternatively, you can use [this](https://github.com/kevinrenskers/SDWebImage-ProgressView) library, or [this one](https://github.com/JJSaccolo/UIActivityIndicator-for-SDWebImage) which is [referred to](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/SDWebImage/3.7.3/#user-content-add-a-progress-indicator) in the `SDWebImage` docs.

As for the background thread issue, wrap the progress update in a dispatch block:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  [progressView setPercentage:(receivedSize*1.0f) /  expectedSize];
});
```

Comment: I have updated the code with your code. Also edited the question and now the progress view is not even visible. Look at the question in the code now. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Check cocoapod SDWebImage-CircularProgressView on github:
https://github.com/NikKovV/SDWebImage-CircularProgressView

By this pod you can implement

- Circular (using DACircularProgress)
- Linear
- Custom

ProgressViews.

This is a category of UIImageView.

For example

```
-(void)nkv_setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url usingProgressViewType:(ProgressViewType)progressViewType orCustomProgressView:(UIProgressView *)progressView;
```

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4**

```
mediumImageView.setImageWith(imageUrl, placeholderImage: placeHolder, options: [.progressiveDownload], usingProgressIndicatorWithProgressTintColor: UIColor.red, andTrackTintColor: UIColor.blue))
```

Comment: Please explain the answer.